# Using onConfigurationChanged Method; Half Screen goes black in android

Tags: android

my issue is that, I am Using onConfigurationChanged Method of android to handle orientation, but when I rotate the screen from portrait to landscape the half of the screen goes black for few seconds(around 10-15 seconds). What I exactly do is, I am handle visibility of some views when orientation change. Is anyone can help to figure out this problem. Any suggestions are appreciated...thanks in advance.